# Navigation Controller push SFSafariViewController, prevent pop of Safari when egdeswipe back in history

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

I'm pushing a SFSafariViewController onto a navigationController.
I want to go back in safari web-history by using Edgeswipe, and I would also like to pop Safari ViewController if stack of history is equal to 1.

The best example is Slacks iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the navigation controller's gesture recognizer to use one of your classes as a delegate.  Implement

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

and return NO.